# fetch record form single coulmn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get record form product which have multiple website_id in one one column.
I am sharing a screenshot here.
[image]

I am trying to fetech record by  websiteid .if website id equal or match with inside of column then query need to fetch data.

```
$websiteid=1;
    $productAll=Product::where(['category_id'=>$categoryDetials->id,'status'=>1])->whereIn('website_id',$websiteid)->get();
```

Please let me know it's possible becouse whereIn syntax is working for array and column value is comm seprated .
Please help me if you have any possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whereRaw like as

```
    $websiteid = 1;
    $productAll = Product::where(['category_id'=>$categoryDetials->id,'status'=>1])
                          ->whereRaw("find_in_set($websiteid,website_id)")
                          ->get();
```

Comment: Glad it help :) select and up-vote the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is comma separated, you need to explode it to the array like:

```
$websiteIdArray = explode(',', $websiteid);
```

After getting the website id in array, now you can use wherein like:

```
$productAll = Product::where(['category_id'=>$categoryDetials->id,'status'=>1])
                     ->whereIn('website_id',$websiteIdArray)
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use **whereRaw()** and **FIND_IN_SET()**

```
Product::where(['category_id'=>$categoryDetials->id, 'status'=>1])
       ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET(" . $websiteIdArray . ", website_id)")
       ->get();
```